# Python - TypeError: float object is not callable error

Tags: python

Have got the following code so far:

```
class beam(object):

    def __init__(self, E, I, L):
         self.E = E  
         self.I = I  
         self.L = L  
         self.Loads = [(0.0, 0.0)] #[(Force, distance along beam)]

    def getTotalDeflection(self, x):
        """Calculate total deflection of beam due to multiple loads"""
        return sum(self.beamDeflection(loadall, x) for loadall in self.Loads)

    def getSlope(self, x):
        """Calculate gradient at a point x on beam due to deflection
        """
        import scipy.misc
        return scipy.misc.derivative(self.getTotalDeflection, x)
```

For the function getSlope(), I need to calculate the slope by finding the derivative of deflection with respect to x. However, I am getting the following error:

> File "C:/Users/X/Downloads/beamModel.py", line 12, in 
>       class beam(object):   File "C:/Users/X/Downloads/beamModel.py", line 67, in beam
>       print b.getSlope(1.0)   File "C:/Users/X/Downloads/beamModel.py", line 62, in getSlope
>       return scipy.misc.derivative(self.getTotalDeflection, x)   File "C:\Users\X\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\misc\common.py", line
>   258, in derivative
>       val += weights[k]*func(x0+(k-ho)*dx,*args) TypeError: 'float' object is not callable

Comment: Edited to fix the mistake from copying and pasting.

Answer (score 1):

The only way that this could happen is if you pass a `float` to `derivative()` in place of a function:

```
>>> scipy.misc.derivative(1.0, 1.0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/misc/common.py", line 195, in derivative
    val += weights[k]*func(x0+(k-ho)*dx,*args)
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

Are you absolutely sure that your code is as posted? Most likely your code is actually *calling* `self.getTotalDeflection` and therefore passing its return value (a float) to `derivative()`, e.g. your code might be:

```
return scipy.misc.derivative(self.getTotalDeflection(x), x)
```

or similar, when it should really be as you have posted, i.e.

```
return scipy.misc.derivative(self.getTotalDeflection, x)
```